# c print argument list using va_list

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

I have a simple argument list. And I just wanna print it to stdout, but I'm getting wired output before printing "end". Does anyone know where that empty line and unreadable characters come from??

output:

```
start
hello
hello2
hello3
hello 4

UH��AWAVAUATE1�S1�H��HH�E�
end



void printTest(const char* msg, ...) {

    va_list ap;
    int i;
    const char* curMsg=0;
    va_start(ap, msg);
    printf("start\n");

    for(curMsg= msg ;  curMsg!=0 ; curMsg = va_arg(ap,  const char*)){
        printf("%s\n", curMsg);
    }
    printf("end\n");
    va_end(ap);
}



int main(){

    printTest("hello", "hello2", "hello3", "hello 4");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you expect to read a null pointer to terminate the loop when you're not passing one? Change the call to:

```
printTest("hello", "hello2", "hello3", "hello 4", (char *)0);
```

Comment: is there any fix for the for loop, instead of appending a (char*) 0?

Comment: from the documentation:   If there is no next argument, or if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next  argument
       (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), random errors will occur. how do i know if it reaches the end??

Comment: No. "Random errors will occur" is the imprecise language the documentation you're reading is using in place of **the behavior is undefined**. You are not allowed to call `va_arg` past the end of the arguments list, and there is **absolutely no way** to identify the end of the arguments list without indicating it somehow. The common ways are with a sentinel argument (like NULL) at the end or a format string that indicates the number and type of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The va_list list is not NULL-terminated. In fact, it doesn't provide any information about how many arguments there are. Your arguments must provide some indication of how many arguments there are. For example, with printf(), the format argument indicates the number of additional arguments to process.

If you need the list to be NULL-terminated, you'll need to pass NULL as the last argument.